# Spring caching - do not cache in case of error

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am using spring caching, my question is:

How can I control the caching in case the result is an error and the next request could be good?

example:

```
@Cacheable("mycache")
public  ResponceBO getBigObject(String id) throws Exception {

    boolean isError = false;

    ***   load big object from other service,  can be loaded with errors  ***
    isError = true;

    if(error){
       responceBO.setError(true);
    }

    return responceBO;
}
```

In case of an error I don't want to cache the object, what can I do instead?

Comment: How about reading [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition)? Basically use `unless` and the expression you want.

Comment: thank you it's very useful !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest reading the [conditional caching section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) of the reference guide. Basically simply specify a `unless` expression to prevent the caching. (The `result` placeholder is only available for the `unless` statement not the `condition` statement.

```
@Cacheable("mycache", unless="#result.error")
public  ResponceBO getBigObject(String id) throws Exception { ... }
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: is it possible to check like :@Cacheable("mycache", unless="#result!=null && #result.error")  ?

Comment: If would be an or not an and `unless=#result == null || #result.error` something like that, instead of `||` you could try `or`.

Comment: @Deinum,Can we add  Exception to the unless condition so that any exceptions/errors shouldn't be cached

Comment: Exceptions aren't cached so that wouldn't add anything.

Comment: what if it return rx.Single or rx.Observable?

Answer (score 0):

you can use unless param in this case. Like below.

```
unless = "#result == null or !#result.isPresent()"
```

isPresent() only when if your result is optional